# Render block in v-for over object only once vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have an object with this structure

```
object: {
 "prop1": [],
 "prop2": [],
 "prop3": [],
}
```

In my template I want to loop over it and display data in `prop's` but if there is no data in any of them I want to show something like this

```
<div>No data</div>
```

but only once and not for each `prop`

So far I have this

```
<div v-for="(props, index) in object" :key="index">
     <div v-if="!props.length">
        No data
     </div>
 </div>
```

But it shows message 3 times, for each prop.
I'm not sure how to solve it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in a nice way, you should use a computed property.

A computed property is basically a piece of code that give meaningless caclulations meaningful names.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            object: {
                "prop1": [],
                "prop2": [],
                "prop3": [],
            },
        };
    },
    computed: {
        areAllEmpty() {
            return Object.values(this.object).map(e => e.length).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) === 0;
        },
    }
};
```

This can then be used in your template as the following:

```
<template>
    <template v-if="areAllEmpty">
        <div>No data</div>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        <div v-for="(props, index) in object" :key="index">
             I'm index {{ index }} with length {{ props.length }}
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you! But if all arrays are empty `areAllEmpty` is `0` so I think it should be `v-if="!areAllEmpty"` ?

Comment: That in indeed correct, mistakes like this happen when you "test" in "production", modified the code of the computed property instead, so other people can still believe the meaning of what the name implies